# How to calculate balance from debit and credit columns for mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I Have two columns Debit and Credit and want query to calculate balance from debit and credit for individual customer as shown below in the image:
[image]

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Man, the price of these pencils!

Comment: mysql version is mysqlnd 8.0.6

Comment: Mr. Gerard H.Pille , dummy data..... what i want is ledger_balance column as ouput from columns ledger_debit and ledger_credit order by ledger_id

Answer (score -1):

**Got my solution:**
select ledger_date ,ledger_desc ,ledger_debit, ledger_credit, sum(ledger_debit) over (order by ledger_id) - sum(ledger_credit) over (order by ledger_id) as Balance
from tblledger

Comment: As long as there is but one customer. The problem doesn't require window functions (over (...)).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please format your answer using the tools above the edit box.